# Pushing multiple UIViewControllers in NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, xcode5

I have 6 subclassed UIViewControllers connected with push segues with identifiers.

They go A>B>C>D>E>F. I am  unable to find a way how to implement button in the controller A which would automatically stack all controllers up to controller F and display F controller. Stacking should be done in `UINavigationController` instance, not through`(void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated`, because if I use `setViewControllers` method, then I lose segue identifiers. Ty!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do it with `pushViewController:animated:`, like this:

```
// This method belongs to view controller A class
-(void)pushToF {
    // I am assuming that A is already in the navigation controller
    UINavigationController *nav = self.navigationController;
    UIViewController *b =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"B"];
    [nav pushViewController:b animated:NO];
    UIViewController *c =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"C"];
    [nav pushViewController:c animated:NO];
    ... // And so on, until F
    UIViewController *f =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"F"];
    // You can push the last one with animation, so that end users would see it
    [nav pushViewController:f animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot! One question more. If I implement modal view on controller A and I have a pushToF method unside that modal view, how would the code be. I know I have to dismiss modal view programatically first and than execute what you wrote, but I don't know how to structure. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @AndrejTrilavov If `"A"` is modal, you need to get a reference of the navigation controller in a way different from `self.navigationController`. You could also dismiss on the button, and call `pushToF` from `viewWillDisappear:animated:`

Comment: Unfortunately, I have other buttons on VC so `viewWillDisappear:animated:` isn't possible. I know I have to `dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO` on self and implement the code you provided me with, but don't know how to write it. Ty!